# Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've spent days trying to launch any Android program. Even "Hello World" gives me the same error:

```
[2014-10-28 18:07:14 - android19] Android Launch!  
[2014-10-28 18:07:14 - android19] adb is running normally.  
[2014-10-28 18:07:14 - android19] Performing com.example.android19.MainActivity activity launch  
[2014-10-28 18:07:14 - android19] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'first'  
[2014-10-28 18:07:14 - android19] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'first'  
[2014-10-28 18:07:43 - Emulator] Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument
```

Anyone can help? Thanks much!

Answer (score 46):

Try to reduce RAM size of an emulator

In Eclipse

**Window** -> **Android Virtual Device Manager**

Select your device and click **Edit** button in right part of window

Then in **Memory Options** secton find **RAM** parameter and set it to *512* for example. Click **OK** for saving. Now try to re-debug your app

Comment: @Azheng and before message `- Emulator] Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument` you should have available, recommended memory size - set this value.

Comment: I would say that if you have multiple emulated devices we must do this for all

Answer (score 21):

In Android Studio:

1. Open Avd manager
2. Edit the settings for the AVD configuration
3. Click in the "Show Advanced Settings"
4. In the "Memory and Storage" section reduce the RAM size

Answer (score 5):

For me, the default RAM size of emulator was 1 GB RAM which was the issue for me in opening the emulator. I reduced RAM size to 512 MB and it works....

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio:

1. Open AVD Manager and go to Advanced Settings

   Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Your Device > Pencil Icon> Show Advanced Settings > Memory and Storage
2. Reduce RAM size (512 MB worked for me)

[RAM size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n682l.png)

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio:
If you have just updated the studio then you might face this problem.
Try restarting Android Studio. It should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem in android studio, just click on show on disk operation

open config file and find for ram word. Edit size to your desired on and restart the studio.
It worked for me.