# Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android

i have a big problem with Android studio.

whats the solution for this error?

```
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Comment: I believe testing on a real device is much easier but if you insist check this thread out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620765/cannot-set-up-guest-memory-android-arm-invalid-argument

Comment: For Andriod Studio 2.2.2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122718/android-studio-not-running

Comment: for Andriod Studio 2.2.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122718/android-studio-not-running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android studio open **Windows->Select Android Virtual Device Manager->Chose your device->Click Edit button->** Change the RAM parameter to **512 Mb** in the **Memory Options->Save** and **run the emulator** it will work

Emuulators are slow. There's really nothing you can do about it, but there are alternatives to the emulator.

1. [***Genymotion - Prefered***](http://www.genymotion.com/)
2. [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)
3. [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)
4. [YouWave](http://youwave.com/download.html)

Comment: i don't have " eclipse " in ,y laptop .which type of eclipse i have to download ? the one for java or foe c/c++ or something else ?!

Comment: i will check the link and hope it will be useful .

Comment: First choose small devices (for less memory)  : 480x800 etc

Comment: i followed the steps but this message come out Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument"

Comment: What is the size of your laptop's RAM ?

Comment: Do you have real android device (phone or tab ) ?

Comment: 4GB and 2.64 is usable .no i dont have a real android device.

Comment: ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'.i restart it and its appear again :(

Comment: Restart your PC then try .. (Need long time for run emulator )

Comment: it takes one week of searching and trying a lot of solutions ..im really happy now :)  thank you again.