# Android studio not running

Tags: android

I just created my first android project in Android studio .It is the default hello word app.When i ran it in the virtualised emulator i got the following error.Please help me sort it out.

```
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your  
environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
emulator: device fd:576
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use Genymotion light weight emulator instead of default, Check out here : https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

Comment: What is your computer's memory configurations..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HAXM is not working try reinstalling it and set the initial value(768MB recommended) of memory to less than the RAM of your computer. You need to reduce the RAM size of the emulator you are trying to run.  And make sure the emulator is not exceeding the value you set while installing the HAXM. If HAXM is set to 768MB, reduce it to further and set RAM to 512MB set for it to work properly.

Android Studio:

1. `Tools` -> `Android` -> `AVD Manager`
2. Click on `Edit this AVD`
3. Show `Advanced Settings` -> `Memory and Storage`
4. Set `RAM` to `512MB` -> `Finish`

Eclipse:

1. Choose your emulator device and
2. Click `Edit` to edit the configurations.
3. `Window` -> `AVD Manager`
4. Under `Memory Options` you will find `RAM` options. Now set it up to a minimal value such as `512MB`.

Now try running your emulator now. Hopefully it should be able to start now.